# How many ways can I arrange $5$ subjects from $7$ to obtain $50$ number sum total?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $7$ subjects, $10$ marks each. Now I want $50$ marks sum total. Now question is, how many combinations possible to score $50$ marks?

$7\  \text{sub}\cdot 10=70 \ \text{marks}$

I need, $5 \ \text{subjects}\cdot 10=50 \ \text{marks}$

How many possible ways are there to get $50$ marks by choosing $5$ subjects out of $7$?

Comment: Why could you not $10$ marks in $4$ subjects and $5$ marks in two others?  The answer to the question you pose is just $\binom75$, but I question if that's the solution to problem.

Comment: A key concept here is that of a [partition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).